# Create GUI in HTML for a PHP script hosted on AWS

Tags: php, html, user-interface

I have a PHP script hosted on AWS ec2 instance
I ssh ec2 instance, open the script, edit the date and filter and run the script every month that generates invoices for many companies
I wish to create graphic user interface that will do the same. Below is my HTML code. I want to associate my invoice.php in this HTML to capture the date and filter from the form and run the script when I hit go. What should I use

```
<p>Please enter the date range along with time and company filter and click on "Go" to run invoice script</p>


<form action="/action_page.php">Start Date (date and time): <input name="start_time" type="datetime-local" /><br><br>
 End Date   (date and time): <input name="end_time" type="datetime-local" /> <br> 
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="company" value="All Companies" checked> All Companies<br>

  <input type="radio" name="company" value="xyz company Only"> Control Risk Only<br>


<button type="button" id="4" class="btn btn-success">Go</button>
```

Comment: "What should I use" is really broad. Could you expand specifically in what you are having issues with?

Comment: First and foremost your `<form>` tags are all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Fix your `<form>` tags.

Step 2: Give your form a `method`.

Step 3: Give your `button` a type of `submit`.

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">

    Start Date (date and time): <input name="start_time" type="datetime-local" />
    <br><br>

    End Date   (date and time): <input name="end_time" type="datetime-local" />
    <br> 

    <input type="radio" name="company" value="All Companies" checked> All Companies
    <br>

    <input type="radio" name="company" value="xyz company Only"> Control Risk Only
    <br>

    <button type="submit" id="4" class="btn btn-success">Go</button>

</form>
```

Now when you submit to `action_page.php` you will be able to access the variables:

```
$_POST["start_time"];
$_POST["end_time"];
$_POST["company"];
```